# Как можно адаптировать абсолютно с позиционированную картинку справа?

Tags: html, css

```css
  .clients-slider{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.clients-slider-line{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 1s;
    display: flex;
}

.clients-slider-img{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.clients-slider-line-wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 34px;
}

.clients-slider-dots{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 12px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 97px;

}

.clients-slider-dot{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #D4D4D4;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.active-dot{
    background-color: #FE6B01;
}

.clients-slider-title{
    font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-top: 60px;
    color: #050931;
}

.clients-slider-text{
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;
    letter-spacing: -0.015em;
    max-width: 1002px;
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    color: #647685;
}

.clients-slider-continue{
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin-top: 48px;
    color: #647685;
}

/* left-part-images*/

.clients-wrapper-images-left-top{
    position: absolute;
    height: 163px;
    width: 163px;
    top: 115px;
    left: calc((1434/1600)*100%);
    z-index: 5;
}

.clients-wrapper-images-left-middle{
    position: absolute;
    height: 87px;
    width: 87px;
    top: 252px;
    left: 78%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.clients-wrapper-images-left-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    height: 87px;
    width: 87px;
    top: 568px;
    left: 78%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.clients-wrapper-images-bottom-left-end{
    position: absolute;
    width: 163px;
    height: 163px;
    left: calc((1434/1600)*100%);
    top: 544px;
    z-index: 5;
}

/* right-part-images*/

.clients-wrapper-images-right-top{
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    top: 197px;
    left: 14%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.clients-wrapper-images-right-middle{
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    top: 324px;
    left: 2%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.clients-wrapper-images-right-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    height: 103px;
    width: 103px;
    top: 441px;
    left: 7.4%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.clients-wrapper-images-right-bottom-end{
    position: absolute;
    width: 171px;
    height: 171px;
    top: 539px;
    right: 89.2%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <section class="clients">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="clients-wrapper">
                    <div class="clients-wrapper-images">
                        <div class="clients-wrapper-images-left">
                            <img src="img/woman-top-part-left.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-left-top">
                            <img src="img/old-woman.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-left-middle">
                            <img src="img/woman-with-flowers.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-left-bottom">
                            <img src="img/woman-suit.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-bottom-left-end">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clients-wrapper-images-right">
                            <img src="img/woman-asian.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-right-top">
                            <img src="img/man-hat.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-right-middle">
                            <img src="img/man-beard.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-right-bottom">
                            <img src="img/man-young.png" alt="" class="clients-wrapper-images-right-bottom-end">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="clients-title">FAQ</h2>
                    <img src="img/orange-underline-supershort.png" alt="" class="clients-title-img">
                    <p class="clients-subtitle">Qur Clients Say</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clients-slider">
                    <div class="clients-slider-line">
                        <div class="clients-slider-line-wrapper">
                            <img src="img/client-man.png" alt="" class="clients-slider-img">
                            <p class="clients-slider-title">They are Simple Great</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-text">There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing. There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing.</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-continue">They are Simple Great</p>                
                        </div>
                        <div class="clients-slider-line-wrapper">
                            <img src="img/woman-with-flowers.png" alt="" class="clients-slider-img">
                            <p class="clients-slider-title">They are Simple Great</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-text">There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing. There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing.</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-continue">They are Simple Great</p>                
                        </div>
                        <div class="clients-slider-line-wrapper">
                            <img src="img/old-woman.png" alt="" class="clients-slider-img">
                            <p class="clients-slider-title">They are Simple Great</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-text">There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing. There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing.</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-continue">They are Simple Great</p>                
                        </div>
                        <div class="clients-slider-line-wrapper">
                            <img src="img/client-man.png" alt="" class="clients-slider-img">
                            <p class="clients-slider-title">They are Simple Great</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-text">There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing. There are many variations  majori have dum suffered alteration in that of a some form by injected dumm more a randomised the slightly believable. If you are believable. If you are passage of Lorem that Ipsum isn't most a important anything embarrassing.</p>
                            <p class="clients-slider-continue">They are Simple Great</p>                
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clients-slider-dots">
                        <div class="clients-slider-dot active-dot"></div>
                        <div class="clients-slider-dot"></div>
                        <div class="clients-slider-dot"></div>
                        <div class="clients-slider-dot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал через `left: calc((1434/1600)*100%);` не получилось, сразу внизу появляется скролл и изображение выходит за экран, может что-то нужно для calc добавить или есть иной способ адаптации таких изображений.

Comment: Вопрос - зачем использовать лефт для объектов, которые вы хотите разместить справа, если есть райт? зачем эта писанина от левого края, если можно размещать по правому? не понятно...

Comment: Я так понимаю нужно использовать right с минусом, иначе если использовать просто right картинки прижимаются к левому краю страницы.

Comment: Вы просто right 0 поставьте, не ужели не сработает

Comment: Если все правильно сделать, то right: 0; прижмёт к правому краю

Comment: right 0 сработал, просто в процессе верстки пользовался таким решением, в другом блоке, но там выставилось всё криво, и поэтому всё через left делал, думал способ right 0 по всей видимости не рабочий, только как можно сделать адаптацию для абсолютно с позиционированного элемента.